# Trying to use map method instead of for loop using React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use map method use instead of for loop using React Typescript for below code but not working

Actual Code using for loop :

```
renderFunction(perkProgressData) {
    let tiers = [];
    let currentData = { item: {} }
    const data = perkProgressData.perkProgressData
    if (data && data.program && data.program.tiers) {
      tiers = data.program.tiers
      **for (let i = 0; i < tiers.length; i++) {**
        if (tiers[i].tierPerks[0].perkStatus === "UNCLAIMED" ||
          data.currentTierId === tiers[i].tierId) {
          currentData = { item: tiers[i] }
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

tried using .map():(Not Working )

```
renderFunction(perkProgressData) {
    let tiers = [];
    let currentData = { item: {} }
    const data = perkProgressData.perkProgressData
    if (data && data.program && data.program.tiers) {
      tiers = data.program.tiers
      tiers.map((val) => {
        if (val.tierPerks && val.tierPerks[0].perkStatus === "UNCLAIMED" || 
          data.currentTierId === val.tierId) {
            currentData = { item: val }
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `map` in that code. You don't need the new array it creates.

Comment: MAP returns a new array but for loop doesn't. Do you need any a new array?

Comment: if for some reason you don't want to use ```for``` loop, you could use a ```forEach```, but not ```map``` for sure

Comment: Yes, is better to use `forEach` in that case

Comment: @Konstantin - Well, the OP wants to break the loop early (at least, the code they're replacing does), so it would be more of a `some` thing. But really, what they're doing is *finding* something in the array, so `find`. But it's troubling, I've seen a **lot** of this "`map` as a general way to loop through arrays" misunderstanding the last 18-24 months. Someone must be mis-teaching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` isn't the right choice here, you don't need the new array it creates. Also, you want to stop early, which `map` doesn't do (unless you throw an error).

The `for` loop is fine, although you might consider `for-of` instead since you don't use the index:

```
renderFunction(perkProgressData) {
    let tiers = [];
    let currentData = { item: {} };
    const data = perkProgressData.perkProgressData;
    if (data && data.program && data.program.tiers) {
      tiers = data.program.tiers;
      for (const tier of tiers) {
        if (tier.tierPerks[0].perkStatus === "UNCLAIMED" ||
          data.currentTierId === tier.tierId) {
          currentData = { item: tier };
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    // ...
```

Or if you don't need `tiers` after the loop:

```
renderFunction(perkProgressData) {
    let currentData = { item: {} };
    const data = perkProgressData.perkProgressData;
    if (data && data.program && data.program.tiers) {
      for (const tier of data.program.tiers) {
        if (tier.tierPerks[0].perkStatus === "UNCLAIMED" ||
          data.currentTierId === tier.tierId) {
          currentData = { item: tier };
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    // ...
```

If you really want to use an array method, [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would make sense:

```
renderFunction(perkProgressData) {
    const data = perkProgressData.perkProgressData
    let currentData =
      ( data &&
        data.program &&
        data.program.tiers &&
        data.program.tiers.find(tier =>
          tier.tierPerks[0].perkStatus === "UNCLAIMED" || data.currentTierId === tier.tierId
        )
      ) ||  { item: {} };
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me  T.J. Crowder ,Its working